# Extend C struct in C++

Tags: c++, c, struct, casting

I have some C structs that I would like to 'extend' in C++ to add some convenience and type safety. For instance, suppose that my struct is

```
struct vector2D { float x, y; };
```

From a number of sources, I have gathered that the safest way to warp this struct in C++ is to subclass it:

```
struct Vector2D: vector2D { ... };
```

So far so good. However, what I am having difficulties figuring out how I can reinterpret the C struct as the extended version. Suppose I have a C function

```
struct vector2D do_some_stuff(struct vector2D _a, struct vector2D _b) {
 ...
}
```

Within this function, I would like to work with the C++ representation. Since the layouts of `struct vector2D` and `Vector2D` are identical, I though that simple cast would work, e.g.

```
Vector2D a = static_cast<Vector2D>(_a)
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Using a constructor generates horrible boilerplate code.

What is the proper way of doing this, if its at all possible?

Clarification: `do_some_stuff` is a C function and is only intended to be called from C code.

Comment: Is do_some_stuff a pure C function (i.e. extern "C")?

Comment: reinterpretation, to "find" parent type is posssible for parameters by reference (or by pointer), but not by value

Comment: "...From a number of sources, I have gathered that the safest way to warp this struct in C++ is to subclass it..." - Whoever said that is downright silly. Please, stay away from those sources.

Comment: You can cast `_a` to a `Vector2D &`, but it is likely to be undefined behavior. The proper way of doing this is to use free functions.

Comment: @WhiZTiM Do you mind to elaborate on this or give some links? Also, what is a right way instead?

Comment: @WhiZTiM: would you care to provide a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Maybe you could specify what you mean by "convenience" and "type safety", because as it stands, it isn't clear that you need to do anything at all. Just use `vector2D` as is. Add functionality with non-member functions.

Answer (score 2):

Prefer composition over inheritance. That is change your C++ `class Vector2D` to contain an instance of C `struct vector2D` and interface it:

```
class Vector2D {
  vector2D p;
public:
  vector2D& getP() { return p; }
  vector2D const& getP() const { return p; }
  float& x() { return p.x; }
  float& y() { return p.y; }
  float const& x() const { return p.x; }
  float const& y() const { return p.y; }
  // ...
};
```

And then call the C function as:

```
Vector2D v1;
Vector2D v2;
...
auto p = do_some_stuff(v1.getP(), v2.getP());
```

Comment: Your answer is certainly correct one but its an answer to a different question. I do not intend to call `do_some_stuff` from C++ code (that would be indeed quite pointless). I want it to be a C function, taking C data types and reinterpreting those as C++ types.

Comment: @MrMobster You wanna call `do_some_stuff` from C with instances of C++ class? For that you'll have to change the signature of `do_some_stuff`, can you do that?

Comment: No, I want to call the C function from C with C structs but inside that function treat the C structs as if they were C++ structs with identical layout.

Comment: @MrMobster You can use a C struct in C++. The other way around you can't. A C++ class lives in the C++ realm.

Comment: I would say "prefer doing nothing over doing something" if it isn't clear what doing something would achieve. Or unless you get paid by LOC written.

Answer (score 2):

> However, what I am having difficulties figuring out how I can reinterpret the C struct as the extended version.

Um, that's not how inheritance works: your daughter class is a specialization of your mother class, so you can interpret a `Vector2D` as a `vector2d`, but not  the other way around.

Think about it: where should the extension's data come from if it wasn't there in the first place?

What you can do is implement a constructor or cast operator that takes a `vector2d` to initialize a new `Vector2D`.

Other than that, I'd say your whole endeavour is questionable, because it's based on a misunderstanding: The struct you're extending is a C++ class now, different from the C type.

Comment: There is no data in `Vector2D`, so it makes some sense to want to do this.

Comment: Since C++ has no concept of data structure extension, my purpose was to hack the inheritance mechanism to accomplish the same. Note that in this case the subclass is NOT a specialisation as it does not add any new state. The instance layout is identical to the original C struct. The only purpose of the subclass is to add convenient members to be used with the struct.

Comment: @MrMobster Just write non-member functions and you're done.

Comment: @MrMobster nope, that is inherently a misconception: Only one of the following statements can be true: 1. There's no additional state 2. I can safely cast the types at runtime, because C++ can tell a raw `vector2d` from a `Vector2D`.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I have figured the way to do it:

```
Vector2D v = *reinterpret_cast<Vector2D*>(&_v);
```

But juanchopanza's suggestion to use non-member functions is probably the better way to go.

Comment: that's undefined behavior.

Comment: after looking through the documentation for some more time I am inclined to agree with @bolov. It seems this can't be done then in a standard-compatible way. A shame, but I will survive.